# Pass variable from one request to another request in postman prerequisite script

Tags: postman

In my following script,

```
function randomString(minValue, maxValue, dataSet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') {
    if (!minValue) {
        minValue = 4;
        maxValue = 4;
    }

    if (!maxValue) {
        maxValue = minValue;
    }

    let length = _.random(minValue, maxValue),
        randomString = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++)
        randomString += dataSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dataSet.length));
    return randomString;
}

pm.variables.set('randomString', randomString());

let displayNameRAW = `UserName-${pm.variables.get("randomString")}`;
let descriptionRAW = `UserName-${pm.variables.get("randomString")}`;
***Block for creating userid***
pm.sendRequest({
   url: "https://localhost/api/userid",
   method: 'POST',
   header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': `Bearer ${pm.environment.get("BEARTOKEN")}`
   },
   body: {
      mode: 'raw',
      raw: JSON.stringify({

         "displayName": displayNameRAW,
         "description": descriptionRAW
      })
   }
}, function (err, responseBD) {
   const jsonResponseforUserID = responseBD.json();
   const newUsriD = jsonResponseforUserID.id;
   pm.globals.set("USERID", newUsriD);
   if (err) {
      console.log("Group Id Error Details:", err)
   }
   else {
       if(newUsriD == "" || newUsriD == null){
            console.log("Request passed with a null or empty string in the response")}
       else{}
   }
});

***Block for generating token***
let tokenUrl = 'https://login.microsoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token';
const getTokenRequest = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: tokenUrl,
   body: {
      mode: 'formdata',
      formdata: [
         {
            'key': 'username',
            'value': '{{username}}'
         },
         {
            'key': 'password',
            'value': '{{password}}'
         }
      ]
   },
};
pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
   const bearerToken = response.json();
   let accessToken = bearerToken.access_token;
   pm.globals.set("BEARTOKEN", accessToken);
   pm.environment.set("BEARTOKEN",accessToken);
   if (err) {
      console.log("Token Gen Error Details:", err)
   }
});
```

When I am running this script, I am getting two different token.

[image]

How to pass the `accessToken` from the request to another request. And observed there are two block one is generating a `token` and pass it to user creation.

And logically the block which generate the token should be execute first and the user creation should be trigger next? how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: why don't you put them into 2 different normal postman requests? `pm.sendRequest` basically is async, they don't run from top to bottom.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Actually I need both the request at the same pm request

Comment: Separate them use Runner might achieve your goal.

Comment: Let me try, I am trying with wrapping them in different function. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

This is just a work around, as the `request` are `async` and the flow control can be maintained(top to bottom).

So I wrap them functions and I achieved it.

```
function randomString(minValue, maxValue, dataSet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') {
    if (!minValue) {
        minValue = 4;
        maxValue = 4;
    }

    if (!maxValue) {
        maxValue = minValue;
    }

    let length = _.random(minValue, maxValue),
        randomString = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++)
        randomString += dataSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dataSet.length));
    return randomString;
}

function genToken() {
    let tokenUrl = 'https://login.microsoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    const getTokenRequest = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: tokenUrl,
        body: {
            mode: 'formdata',
            formdata: [{
                    'key': 'username',
                    'value': '{{username}}'
                },
                {
                    'key': 'password',
                    'value': '{{password}}'
                }
            ]
        },
    };
    pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
        const bearerToken = response.json();
        let accessToken = bearerToken.access_token;
        pm.globals.set("GRAPHTOKENGLB", accessToken);
        pm.environment.set("GRAPHTOKENENV", accessToken);
        if (err) {
            console.log("Token Gen Error Details:", err)
        }
        createUserId()
    });
}


function createUserId() {

    pm.variables.set('randomString', randomString());

    let displayNameRAW = `UserName-${pm.variables.get("randomString")}`;
    let descriptionRAW = `UserName-${pm.variables.get("randomString")}`;

    pm.sendRequest({
        url: "https://localhost/api/userid",
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${pm.environment.get("GRAPHTOKENENV")}`
        },
        body: {
            mode: 'raw',
            raw: JSON.stringify({

                "displayName": displayNameRAW,
                "description": descriptionRAW
            })
        }
    }, function(err, responseBD) {
        const jsonResponseforUserID = responseBD.json();
        const newUsriD = jsonResponseforUserID.id;
        pm.globals.set("USERID", newUsriD);
        if (err) {
            console.log("Group Id Error Details:", err)
        } else {
            if (newUsriD == "" || newUsriD == null) {
                console.log("Request passed with a null or empty string in the response")
            } else {}
        }
    });
}


genToken()
```